# Criar tabela em SQLite com array

Tags: sqlite

Estou a criar uma Base de Dados em SQLIte e tenho 2 tabelas, uma tabela LISTA e outra PRODUTOS.
A tabela LISTA para além dos campos `ID numeric`, `NOME text`, tem um ARRAYLIST de PRODUTOS.
Já a tabela PRODUTOS só tem `ID numeric`, `NOME text`, `IMAGEM drawable`.

A minha dúvida é como criar a tabela LISTA em SQLite, se os tipos do SQLITE permitidos não contemplam ARRAYLISTs?

Comment: Me parece que você está tentando transformar classes em tabelas. Isto não dá certo. Tem que adaptar. A pergunta está um pouco confusa, por mais que eu queira ajudar, não consigo por não entender exatamente o que está fazendo, não ter informações suficientes, e nem qual sua real dúvida. Se conseguir melhorar, eu respondo.

Comment: @bigown, Estou a fazer uma app, em que cada lista contem um conjunto de produtos e em que o user pode ir adicionando sempre mais produtos, daí estar a colocar a questão do array. 
A tua sugestão é que em vez de ter um array tenha na tabela LISTA só o ID do PRODUTO (para além do que já tenho, ID da lista e nome da Lista)? Consegui explicar-me?

Comment: Infelizmente não dá para entender o problema que você está tendo, a informação está muito truncada. Talvez ajude se colocar o código da aplicação, a estrutura do SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

Essa tabela que voce chama de lista deve ter um nome tipo: clientes, produtos, pessoas, aviões, carros, etc. Dê nome a sua tabela no SQLite e somente depois que voce tiver registros dentro dela é que voce podera criar uma lista desta tabela em  Java.

Assumindo que você criou uma tabela de carros que tem seus campos id e nome, então:

```
 - ID     NOME
 - 1      OMEGA
 - 2      PASSAT
 - 3      FUSCA
```

Feito isso, basta o uma lista com a classe `Util` em Java:

```
List<Carros> lista_de_carros = new ArrayList<Carros>();
```

Answer (score 0):

O Sqlite não tem o tipo *ArrayList* porque tal não faz sentido.
O *ArrayList* é um tipo que representa uma lista e uma lista é representada, no Sqlite(e não só), por uma tabela.

Assim, deverá ter uma tabela para a(s) lista(s) e outra para os itens de cada lista.

Será qualquer coisa assim:

```
| Listas |
|________|
| Id     |
| Nome   |
|  ...   |
|  ...   |
|________|

|   Itens   |
|___________|
| Id        |
| ListaId   |
| ProdutoId |
| Quantidade|
|    ...    |
|    ...    |
|___________|
```

Os campos `ListaId` e `ProdutoId` deverão ser declarados como [ForeignKey](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) em referência às tabelas **Listas** e **Produtos**, respectivamente.